# Make a simple query to a website from Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib, urllib2

I want to programmatically search a website and receive data using Python.

There are two fields I want to fill out:

```
<input name="ctl00$centerHolder$tbFName" type="text" value="" maxlength="64" id="ctl00_centerHolder_tbFName">
```

and

```
<input name="ctl00$centerHolder$tbLName" type="text" value="" maxlength="64" id="ctl00_centerHolder_tbLName">
```

And finally, I want to "hit" search which is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$centerHolder$search" value="Search" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$centerHolder$search&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_centerHolder_search">
```

Can anyone please point out how to do this? I have no web knowledge, just some basic html.

Thank you!

Comment: you probably want to look into a library like selenium

Comment: Can you give the website url?